# how to truncate a number after it exceeds a certain string?

Tags: vba

I have this VBA code:

```
c = "00799999" & Format(Compte, String$(12, "0"))
```

When I type for example 111111111193 the result will be 00799999111111111193.
When I type 30003470 i get as a result 00799999000030003470
(the to examples work fine). (I.E twelve characters or less).

The problem I want to solve is than when i type more than twelve numbers, for example:
9123456789123 or 99123456789123 or 999123456789123 or 9999123456789123 or 99999123456789123
or 799999123456789123 or 0799999123456789123, or finally 00799999123456789123 I want the code to truncate always the twelve numbers from the right and add 0079999,for example 9000030003470 is thirteen characters, the code will remove the 9 from the left and add instead 0079999.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Where do you "type"? In a cell/a text box and do you have an event to concatenate  the last 12 digits with "00799999"? Or what? You must say something about context. To create a reproductible example...

Comment: In a cell.   When I apply this : Option Explicit

Public Function CDZEman(Compte$, Clé As Range, _
                    Optional mois$, Optional année$) As String
  On Error GoTo ErrMA
  Dim DS As Date, M As Byte, A%, c$, cler$, chn$, d&
  c = "00799999" & Format(Compte, String$(12, "0"))
 The remain of the code is OK

Comment: ``c = "00799999" & right("000000000000" & CStr(Compte),12) ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an easy fix which will work for numbers with either more or less than 12 characters. If the number is less than 12 characters then it will be padded with zeros on the left. If more than 12 characters then the number will be truncated to the 12 rightmost characters which gives the result you want:

```
c = "00799999" & Format(Right(Compte, 12), String$(12, "0"))
```

Comment: why when I type the whole account number i get a false result. the acount number is 00799999000030003470? when i type 999000030003470 the result is right, by when i add the other "00799" i get a false result

Comment: The length of « Compte » is 20 strings.
It always begins with 00799999 and then 12 numbers to make it 20.
In normal cases, when I type the « compte » number, I enter twelve numbers. Eg. 123456789103
So the code c = "00799999" & Format(Right(Compte, 12), String$(12, "0")) will give me 00799999123456789103, but for an unaware person if he types 00799999123456789103 he will get 
00799999234567890000 instead of 00799999123456789103.

Comment: I checked your scenario and could not reproduce what you are saying. `Right(Compte, 12)` will always get the last 12 characters. If the user types 00799999123456789103 then `Right(Compte, 12)` will return 123456789103 which will then have 00799999 prepended to it.